# Mysql. Как выбрать из базы данных имя имея только login?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Это база таблица базы данных. Из которои мне нужно взять name имея только login. Помогите!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE login='my_login'`

Если еще нужна реализация на `php` посмотрите в сторону `PDO` - http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php там есть примеры

Comment: Спасиба сейчас проверю данный способ.

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name FROM название_таблицы WHERE login = 'логин_пользователя';

подробнее изучайте http://2sql.ru/basic/sql-select/